# Pick up the value for the next selected email

Tags: vba, for-loop, outlook

I have two "For" statements that should pick up the currently selected outlook mail item then each email attachment.

While watching the code via "Step Into", after it processes the last attachment for the currently selected email it does not get the new value for `olItem.Body`. The script continues to use the `olItem.Body` from the first email.

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk()
Scripts in Rules
    Dim itm         As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
    Dim Selection   As Selection
    Dim strFileName As String, strExt As String
    Dim objAtt      As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder  As String
    Dim email_date  As Date
    Dim date_ext    As String
    Dim sText       As String
    Dim Intext_date As String
    Dim Mail_date   As Date
    Dim email_date_temp As String
    
    saveFolder = "C:\elan\Various\email_attachments\"
    
    Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection
    
    For Each itm In Selection
        For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
            
            strFileName = objAtt.DisplayName
            
            ' get the last 5 characters or last 4 for .xls for the file extension
            strExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, 5)
            
            If Mid(strExt, 1, 1) <> "." Then
                strExt = Right(objAtt.DisplayName, 4)
                
            End If
            If strExt = ".xls" Or strExt = ".xlsx" Then
                ' clean the File Name
                ReplaceCharsForFileName strFileName, "-"
                
                ' Get Body of email
                
                Set olItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
                sText = olItem.Body
                Debug.Print sText
                'determine lenght of string date field
                
                'Find the correct date format based of day of the week
                If InStr(1, sText, "Monday") > 1 Then
                    Intext_date = Mid(sText, InStr(1, sText, "Monday"), (InStr(InStr(1, sText, "Monday") + 8, sText, ",") + 6) - InStr(1, sText, "Monday"))
                ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "Tuesday") > 1 Then
                    Intext_date = Mid(sText, InStr(1, sText, "Tuesday"), (InStr(InStr(1, sText, "Tuesday") + 8, sText, ",") + 6) - InStr(1, sText, "Tuesday"))
                ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "Wednesday") > 1 Then
                    Intext_date = Mid(sText, InStr(1, sText, "Wednesday"), (InStr(InStr(1, sText, "Wednesday") + 8, sText, ",") + 6) - InStr(1, sText, "Wednesday"))
                ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "Thursday") > 1 Then
                    Intext_date = Mid(sText, InStr(1, sText, "Thursday"), (InStr(InStr(1, sText, "Thursday") + 8, sText, ",") + 6) - InStr(1, sText, "Thursday"))
                ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "Friday") > 1 Then
                    Intext_date = Mid(sText, InStr(1, sText, "Friday"), (InStr(InStr(1, sText, "Friday") + 8, sText, ",") + 6) - InStr(1, sText, "Friday"))
                ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "Saturday") > 1 Then
                    Intext_date = Mid(sText, InStr(1, sText, "Saturday"), (InStr(InStr(1, sText, "Saturday") + 8, sText, ",") + 6) - InStr(1, sText, "Saturday"))
                ElseIf InStr(1, sText, "Sunday") > 1 Then
                    Intext_date = Mid(sText, InStr(1, sText, "Sunday"), (InStr(InStr(1, sText, "Sunday") + 8, sText, ",") + 6) - InStr(1, sText, "Sunday"))
                Else
                    Intext_date = "No_Date_Found"
                End If
                'Change Date Format
                Mail_date = CDate(Mid(Intext_date, InStr(Intext_date, ",") + 2))
                ' put the name and extension together
                email_date_temp = Format(Mail_date, "yyyy-mm-dd")
                file = saveFolder & strFileName & "@" & email_date_temp & strExt
                
                objAtt.SaveAsFile file
                
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
    
Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
            sChr As String _
            )
    sName = Replace(sName, "'", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "*", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "\", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
    sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: You use `itm` and `olItem`, which is the correct one? `olItem` is hard coded to the first selected item.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the following lines of code:

```
Set olItem = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
sText = olItem.Body
```

You need to use the `itm` object from the loop to get message body string from the item currently iterated:

```
sText = itm.Body
```